# How does Python's global/nonlocal work under the hood?

Tags: python, scope

How does Python manage to locate a `global`/`nonlocal` variable so quickly even if the recursion is thousands of layers deep? Also why do only need `global`/`nonlocal` for primitive data types and not pointers?

Comment: Python is *statically scoped*, so depth of recursion is irrelevant.  Also, it doesn't support recursion "thousands of layers deep".

Comment: What do you mean with "so quickly"? Compared to what? Also, you should be asking one question only. Currently there are two, and that is a reason to close this question.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sure it does. You just need to adjust the default recursion limit (and have enough memory to handle an increased limit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does Python manage to locate a global/nonlocal variable so quickly even if the recursion is thousands of layers deep?

A useful reference (as far as CPython goes) is: [TenThousandMeters](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-5-how-variables-are-implemented-in-cpython/).  The key points from this is that (1) globals are accessible through the bytecode  instruction `LOAD_GLOBAL`, (2) declared nonlocals are 'cell variables' directly accessible to a code block. The VM doesn't need to somehow iterate through the previous frames on the call stack to get to them.

> Also why do only need global/nonlocal for primitive data types and not
> pointers?

I think what you're getting at here is: why can we do something like `my_list.append(42)` if `my_list` comes from an enclosing scope, without needing a `nonlocal` declaration, whereas if we do `x = x + 42` we do need to have declared `nonlocal x`?

The key point here is that `x = x + 42` *reassigns the name `x` to refer to a different object* and requires a `nonlocal` declaration.  But `my_list.append(42)` doesn't reassign a name.  `my_list` refers to the *same* object before and after the statement: the effect of the statement is to perform an operation on that mutable object, and `nonlocal` isn't needed here: just like it isn't when you call a method on `my_list` which happens to leave it unchanged.

This isn't exactly about primitive data types vs others.  For example, `my_list = [i+2 for i in my_list]` does reassign `my_list` to point to a newly created object, and needs `nonlocal`.